# Ionic build android --prod cleancss broken @import error

Tags: android, css, ionic-framework, sass, ionic2

I'm trying to use custom fonts in my app. I have 2 fonts, one is a icon font from flaticons and another is the text font "Humanst webfont", i've downloaded them both and followed lots of tutorials on how to make them work, here is what i've got so far:

THE ERROR:
[Erro thrown of broken import](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8UcOi.png)

MY PROJECT FOLDERS: [THE SRC AND WWW FOLDERS](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5HKOm.png)

And i have this in my app.scss:

```
@import "../assets/fonts/humanst-webfont.css";
@import "../assets/fonts/flaticon.css";
```

This is my humans-webfotn.css:

```
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Humanst';
  src: url('humanst-webfont.woff2') format('woff2'),
       url('humanst-webfont.woff') format('woff');
  font-weight: normal;
  font-style: normal;
}
```

i've tryed importing the .css, the .scss and letting just humanst-webfont. Updated my appscripts to 1.0.0 too.
In ionic serve it works fine, but when i try to build it breaks. Does someone know what it is?

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was having the same problem. I ended putting the css in the index.html instead of the variables file.
Worked fine during production build and during serve.

Comment: this worked for me, a simples style tag with the @font-face was enough. Thank you

Comment: Still tho, why android build can not include css file? I have animate.css in my project and I am having the issue. Any official fix for this?